# searching item in a knockout observable array case insensitive

Tags: knockout.js, comparison, observable

I am trying to compare items in 2 arrays:

```
   ko.utils.arrayForEach(arrList, function (item) {
     if (arrList2().findIndex(a => item.toLowerCase() === a.toLowerCase())>=0) {
          // found similar item in arrlist2, so, handle it
     }
    }
```

But this is not working. Basically, I want to check if an element in arrList is present in arrList2 (case insensitive check), both are ko observable arrays. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `var differences = ko.utils.compareArrays(arrList(), arrList2());`
It will give you an array with items that looks like this `{status: "added", value: originalItem}`

The status will be one of these three values `added, deleted, retained`
Have a look at this article - [Utility Functions in KnockoutJS](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html)

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Test 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Test 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Test 3"
  }
];

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.list1 = ko.observableArray(data.slice(0));
  self.list2 = ko.observableArray(data.slice(0));

  var item = data[0];
  self.list2.remove(item);
  self.list2().push({
    id: 5,
    name: "Test 5"
  });

  self.listDiff = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return ko.utils.compareArrays(self.list1(), self.list2());
  });

  self.listReverseDiff = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return ko.utils.compareArrays(self.list2(), self.list1());
  });

  self.sameItems = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return self.list1().filter(function(item1) {
      var arr = self.list2().filter(function(item2) {
        return (
          item1.name.toString().toLowerCase() ===
          item2.name.toString().toLowerCase()
        );
      });
      return arr.length > 0;
    });
  });
}
var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h3>List 1</h3>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(list1)"></pre>
<h3>List 2</h3>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(list2)"></pre>
<h3>Items in List 1 that exist in List 2</h3>
 <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(sameItems)"></pre>
 
<h3>List 1</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: list1">
  <li><span data-bind="text: id"></span> - <span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
</ul>

<h3>List 2</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: list2">
  <li><span data-bind="text: id"></span> - <span data-bind="text: name"></span></li>
</ul>


<h3>List1 vs List2 differences</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: listDiff">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: status"></span>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>
  </li>
</ul>


<h3>List2 vs List1 differences</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: listReverseDiff">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text: status"></span>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a bit extensive, but serves the purpose. I just switched over to using a function: function( element, array ) {
                        var len = array.length;
                        var str = element.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
                             var arr = array[i];
                             if ( arr.toLowerCase() == str ) {
                                return i;
                             }
                        }
                        return -1;
       };

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.prototype.map` to create an all lowercase version of arrayList2, and then finding out if an item from arrayList1 also occurs in arrayList2 would be trivial:

```
let arrList2LC = arrList2().map((item) => item.toLowerCase());

arrList1().forEach((item) => {
    if (arrList2LC.indexOf(item.toLowerCase() > -1) {
        // item is present in arrList2
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the element I am comparing will also need to be in lower case, right? I switched over to using a function.